# Solr UI, Highlighting, and EscapeTool

Tags: configuration, solr, velocity, html-escape-characters

I'm using the tool "Escape Tool" from the default Solr toolkit.  I use it to display text fields that might have html tags embedded in them.  I do this at the velocity UI document level.  I.e. I escape it right before it displays.

I want to turn on highlighting, and have successfully done so via solrconfig:

```
<str name="hl">false</str>
<str name="hl.fl">*</str>
<str name="hl.usePhraseHighlighter">true</str>
<str name="hl.requireFieldMatch">true</str>
<str name="hl.regex.maxAnalyzedChars">10000</str>
<str name="hl.useFastVectorHighlighter">true</str>
```

Unfortunately, the escape tool escapes the default tag (em) so it doesn't really work the way its intended.  Moving the escape procedure before the highlighting takes place sounds like the optimal solution.  I'm not too familiar with the order things are applied by the UI on output.

One way to do it is to escape the fields on insertion: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/webapps.html using org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.EscapeHtmlReference.  But I was wondering if there was a way to do it without modifying the content stored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different highlight tag, e.g use something very unlikely in the input

```
<str name="hl.simple.pre">:-:${</str>
<str name="hl.simple.post">}:-:</str>
```

and then replace that back to your preferred highlight tag (e.g. `<em>`)